# How to associate an Eclipse sample Editor with a file in project explorer view

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have an sample editor which opens up by selecting an action from a sample Menu created in the menu bar.

How do i associate this editor with a file in Project explorer view?

I mean if i double click on the file in project explorer view , the editor should spawn up.

Basically i want this editor to work like a regular eclipse editor.

Please let me know your suggestions or any online material which explains the framework  on how to achieve this.

Thanks,
Karthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `IWorkbenchPage.openEditor(IEditorInput input, String editorId)`. Here you specify the input object of the editor and the ID for the editor.

In a RCP application, the `IEditorInput` is usually made up by you - nothing fancy is needed unless you want to persist the editors - and ID is specified via the `org.eclipse.ui.editors`.

Comment: In the plugin.xml i have added this entry"extensions = "tdf" :

     <editor
            name="%baseEditor"
            extensions="tdf"
            default="true"
               class="org.eclipse.ui.forms.article.rcp.SimpleFormEditor"
            id="org.eclipse.ui.forms.article.base-editor">
      </editor>

Now when i create a sample.tdf file and try to open the editor i'm getting exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.ui.part.FileEditorInput cant be cast to org.eclipse.ui.forms.article.rcp.SimpleFormEditorInput

Please let me know your suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use an existing editor implementation - `SimpleFormEditor` - from an article... but you must always conform the wanted `IEditorInput` supported by the editor - in this case `SimpleFormEditorInput`. You must either 1) create your own editor and match the input requirements (a file?) or 2) create the correct editor input before calling `openEditor(...)`.

Comment: ok now the editor gets opened when i double click the file. But how do i get the File->Save enabled for this file?

I mean how do i save the data contained in my editor ? (My editor extends FormEditor).